# Understanding deadlock behavior with gdb

Tags: gdb, deadlock

I am hunting down a deadlock, but I don't understand gdb behavior in this respect. I have two threads:

```
Thread 2 (Thread 0x2aaaadf66940 (LWP 10229)):
#0  0x0000003f95e0d654 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003f95e08f65 in _L_lock_1127 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000003f95e08e63 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00002b67cbdeaded in ?? ()
#4  0x000000002d0e9608 in ?? ()
#5  0x00002b67cbd1e1f2 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000000000000b in ?? ()
#7  0x00002aaaca08e410 in ?? ()
#8  0x00002aaab405d558 in ?? ()
#9  0x00002aaaadf65f48 in ?? ()
#10 0x00002aaaadf65fa0 in ?? ()
#11 0x00002aaaadf65fc0 in ?? ()
#12 0x00002aaaadf65f40 in ?? ()
#13 0x00002aaaadf65f50 in ?? ()
#14 0x000000002d0e7460 in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000026014330 in ?? ()
#16 0x00002b67cc1d08b0 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000003f94e7587b in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#18 0x00002aaac8b67450 in ?? ()
#19 0x00002aaaadf66070 in ?? ()
#20 0x13477fb9fe21aee8 in ?? ()
#21 0x000003742e856f43 in ?? ()
#22 0x00002b67cbe11811 in ?? ()
#23 0x00002b67cc1cfc70 in ?? ()
#24 0x000000002d0e8328 in ?? ()
#25 0x000000002d0e9630 in ?? ()
#26 0x00002b67cbded355 in ?? ()
#27 0x0000000052cdceee in ?? ()
#28 0x000000002d0e9608 in ?? ()
#29 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#30 0x000000002d0e9700 in ?? ()
#31 0x000000002d0e96a8 in ?? ()
#32 0x000000002d0e9728 in ?? ()
#33 0x000000002d0e9630 in ?? ()
#34 0x00002b67cbded538 in ?? ()
#35 0x000000002ccbc6a8 in ?? ()
#36 0x00002aaaadf66070 in ?? ()
#37 0xfffffffffffffffe in ?? ()
#38 0x0000000000000008 in ?? ()
#39 0x00002b67cbe0cf00 in ?? ()
#40 0x0000003b24002216 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.319.60
#41 0x00002b67cbe116ec in ?? ()
#42 0x000000002d0e9648 in ?? ()
#43 0xffffffffffffff01 in ?? ()
#44 0x00002b67cc1f38f8 in ?? ()
#45 0x00002b67cbe103fa in ?? ()
#46 0x0000000019eac470 in ?? ()
#47 0x0000000034bc8ef0 in ?? ()
#48 0x00000000ffffffff in ?? ()
#49 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 0x2b67c311c600 (LWP 9798)):
#0  0x0000003f95e0d654 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003f95e08f4a in _L_lock_1034 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000003f95e08e0c in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00002b67cbdf02a8 in ?? ()
#4  0x000000000000b000 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000000b000 in ?? ()
#6  0x000000002d0e7460 in ?? ()
#7  0x00002aaad484e6c0 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fffd540a1b0 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000003f94e73f0e in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#10 0x0000003b24002216 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.319.60
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

These two threads are apparently deadlocking: Thread 1 wants to acquire the lock from thread 2 (note the owner)

```
(gdb) p *(pthread_mutex_t*)0x2d0e9648
$1 = {__data = {__lock = 2, __count = 0, __owner = 10229, __nusers = 1, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}},
```

and thread 2 wants to acquire the lock from thread 1

```
(gdb) p *(pthread_mutex_t*)0x2d0e8330
$2 = {__data = {__lock = 2, __count = 1, __owner = 9798, __nusers = 1, __kind = 1, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}},
```

Now, What I don't understand is why the backtrace is so broken. I tried checking which libraries are mapped to those address (in particular the 2b67cbd) but none do. I tried a disas. no luck:

```
 (gdb) disas 0x00002b67cbdeaded
 No function contains specified address.
```

There seems to be nothing on those addresses. I thought it was a stack corruption, but then what is happening that actually calls the pthread lock? Who sends the thread to that code? and how reliable is the call to free() (note that the other thread is doing a call to malloc, so they might be related in their activity)?

Comment: `how reliable is the call to free()`. What if you do a test. Set a breakpoint on free and see if any calls to free() come from /usr/lib64/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.319.60? I mean restarting your application, setting a breakpoint on free and collecting backtraces to free() (or only from this library)?

Comment: skwllsp: It's actually a bit complicated to do so. It's not the application that deadlocks. It's a testsuite that lasts many hours, and does not deadlock all the time, just once in a while. Additionally, I have the suspect that if I start gdbing the running suite, it will change the timings and lead nowhere.

Comment: skwllsp: I simply don't understand how the stack can be so messed up and refer to code that apparently is not there. Is it really corrupted, or there's something I don't know about that prevents me to see where and what code is present at those addresses? Dynamic loading? I don't know...

Comment: `I simply don't understand how the stack can be so messed up and refer to code that apparently is not there`. But this is my point. Set a breakpoint and get stacktraces just to make sure that calls to free from this library are correct before the deadlock(). Are you sure that they are correct?

Comment: And are you sure that all shared libraries are present? I mean that `info shared` shows

Comment: @skwllsp: apparently, all libraries are present. I don't know how it would behave with dlopened stuff, but as far as I can see, all that must be there is there.

Comment: Could it be that the debugging information for the test code is missing?

Comment: @flup: ok but if that was the case, I would not get info from the other threads, and at least I would get code at that address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `(gdb) disas 0x00002b67cbdeaded`
>
> No function contains specified address.
>   There seems to be nothing on those addresses.

Your conclusion is likely not correct. Try `(gdb) x/20i 0x00002b67cbdeaded-5`, and you'll see that in fact there is code there, including a `CALL pthread_mutex_lock`.

What's likely happening is that something in your program is using a JIT compiler, and the code that calls `pthread_mutex_lock` does not have any symbols (that GDB knows about) associated with it.

That code also doesn't have any unwind descriptors, which makes the rest of the stack completely unreliable. `free` and `malloc` may or may not be actually on stack.

It may be illustrative to look at /proc//maps and see what is mapped in the `0x00002b67cbdea000` region. Most likely you'll find anonymous mapping with `rwxp` permissions.

Comment: `What's likely happening is that something in your program is using a JIT compiler`. the code that is running is cPython, and all other threads show symbol and where they are. I haven't tried to do as you said, because I had to reboot the machine for other reasons and thus I lost the deadlock condition. It presents itself rather often so I will try again.

Comment: You were quite close. I still don't know what's going on, but at least I understood that you are right in saying that there's something at that address, and it's basically a call to a jump table. So the stack is not corrupted, it's just that it's used in a "creative way" by the compiler. How, and why I get a deadlock, is still a mystery.